# How to do a Zend DbTable fetchAll in descending order

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm writing a Zend 1.12 application involving election results. I can use the DbTable fetchAll to retrieve only candidates in a specific riding, but I'd like to order them by vote from most to least (DSC) (instead of the default least to most (ASC)).

```
//class Application_Model_CandidateMapper
public function fetchForRiding($riding)
{
    $where = 'riding = %s';
    $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll(sprintf($where, $riding), 'votes');
    //blah blah blah
    return $candidates
}
```

This gets the candidates for the riding and orders them by vote, but in ASC instead of DSC. I tried to jack 'DSC' into the fetchAll arguments a few different ways and the database complained it was being asked to `ORDER BY 'votes DSC' ASC`.

Comment: WHy don't you try 

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY DESC';
 $result = $db->fetchAll($sql);

Comment: A reason I don't is because I don't specify the table name anywhere in the mapper classes, only in the Application_Model_DbTable classes. But I can easily change things around so that would work. More importantly, I feel like I'm defeating the purpose of using a framework when I'm writing manual queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: its `DESC`, not `DSC` :) Simply use zend functions instead of plain sql (as mentioned in the comment):

```
public function fetchForRiding($riding)
{
    $select = $this->getDbTable()->select();
    $select->where('riding = ?', $riding);
    $select->order('votes DESC');

    $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select);

    [...]

    return $candidates
}
```

(untested)